# Can netty handle re-segmented TLS records?

Tags: netty

Since there is no correspondence between NIO TCP read events (essentially TCP buffered segments) and the TLS records carried as payload inside them, I am trying to figure out if Netty handles correctly TLS records that are randomly re-segmented into separate NIO reads.

In SSLEngine.unwrap() this would cause a BUFFER_UNDERFLOW which is handled simply by breaking the loop here:
https://github.com/netty/netty/blob/master/handler/src/main/java/io/netty/handler/ssl/SslHandler.java#L483

Does anyone have experience with re-segmentation and if this code is sufficient to recover TLS records in all cases? Any advice on testing it would be appreciated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is yes. After breaking the loop, the `unwrap()` method will be called again when more data is received.  If you find a bug where `SslHandler` doesn't handle re-segmented TLS records, please file a bug so that we can fix it.